# Regex matching multilines linux bash

Tags: regex, sed, grep

I have a big .warc file which contains a lot of records. I want to extract headers from it in bash script.

Let's take a look.

File looks like this:

```
WARC/1.0
WARC-Type: response
Content-Length: 2597724
WARC-Date: 2016-05-07T03:36:46Z
WARC-Payload-Digest: sha1:33a3973a118293e4f8831449cc37095d645a57b3
WARC-Target-URI: url
Content-Type: application/http; msgtype=response
WARC-Record-ID: <urn:uuid:ecc531d0-1404-11e6-a7dc-002590c8c43c>

<!DOCTYPE html>
//some html code

WARC/1.0
WARC-Type: response
Content-Length: 2106841
WARC-Date: 2016-05-07T03:36:51Z
WARC-Payload-Digest: sha1:826fcc2ef666e2cfbcff9e4329a293141077a20e
WARC-Target-URI: url
Content-Type: application/http; msgtype=response
WARC-Record-ID: <urn:uuid:efa655dc-1404-11e6-a7dc-002590c8c43c>

<!DOCTYPE html>
//some html code

etc...
```

I want extract only headers information and make output like this (.csv file - every information from header as one column):

```
WARC-Type(from first header)\tContent-Length(from first header)\tWARC-Date(from first header)\tWARC-Payload-Digest(from first header)\tWARC-Target-URI(from first header)\tContent-Type(from first header)\tWARC-Record-ID
WARC-Type(from second header)\tContent-Length(from second header)\tWARC-Date(from second header)\tWARC-Payload-Digest(from second header)\tWARC-Target-URI(from second header)\tContent-Type(from second header)\tWARC-Record-ID
```

I made regular expression matching this headers:

```
REGULAR_EXPRESSION='WARC\/1\.0\nWARC-Type\:.*\nWARC-Date\:.*\nWARC-Payload-Digest:.*\nWARC-Target-URI:.*\nWARC-Record-ID:.*\n\n'
```

I cannot use grep with -P parameter. So I don't have any idea how to continue. Maybe sed? And next problem after match regular expression. How to extract proper information?

What is the best way to achieve goal?

Comment: @anubhava sorry for my bad information. I updated my question. Now it is more clearer. Thanks for help.

Comment: Your question is an [X/Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Tell us what problem you are trying to solve instead of asking for help with the solution, which does not appear to be the correct approach.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson  I don't think so. I wrote - I cannot use grep with -P parameter. So I don't have any idea how to continue. I need match my regex expression and then pipeline (|) to another program. I don't need find right solution. I need help which programs should I use, That's all.

Comment: [*Some people, when confronted with a problem, think “I know, I'll use regular expressions.”  Now they have two problems.* - Jamie Zawinski](http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247)

Answer (score 1):

It is easier to handle this with `awk`:

```
awk -F ': ' -v OFS='\t' 'NF>=2 {
   printf "%s%s", $2, ($1 != "WARC-Record-ID" ? OFS : ORS)}' file

response    2597724 2016-05-07T03:36:46Z    sha1:33a3973a118293e4f8831449cc37095d645a57b3   url application/http; msgtype=response  <urn:uuid:ecc531d0-1404-11e6-a7dc-002590c8c43c>
response    2106841 2016-05-07T03:36:51Z    sha1:826fcc2ef666e2cfbcff9e4329a293141077a20e   url application/http; msgtype=response  <urn:uuid:efa655dc-1404-11e6-a7dc-002590c8c43c>
```

Comment: @Joozty: Did this work out?

Answer (score 0):

***awk*** solution:

```
awk -F': ' '/WARC-Type/{n=NR+6}NR<=n{ s="\t"; if(NR==n){n=0;s=ORS} printf "%s%s",$2,s }' file
```

The output:

```
response    2597724 2016-05-07T03:36:46Z    sha1:33a3973a118293e4f8831449cc37095d645a57b3   url application/http; msgtype=response  <urn:uuid:ecc531d0-1404-11e6-a7dc-002590c8c43c>
response    2106841 2016-05-07T03:36:51Z    sha1:826fcc2ef666e2cfbcff9e4329a293141077a20e   url application/http; msgtype=response  <urn:uuid:efa655dc-1404-11e6-a7dc-002590c8c43c>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very unclear and your example doesn't tell us anything that would help us avoid false matches (the hardest part of any matching script) but is this what you're trying to do?

```
$ awk -v RS= -v FS='\n[^:]+: *' -v OFS='\t' 'sub(/^WARC\/[0-9.]+/,""){$1=$1; sub(OFS,""); print}' file
response        2597724 2016-05-07T03:36:46Z    sha1:33a3973a118293e4f8831449cc37095d645a57b3   url     application/http; msgtype=response      <urn:uuid:ecc531d0-1404-11e6-a7dc-002590c8c43c>
response        2106841 2016-05-07T03:36:51Z    sha1:826fcc2ef666e2cfbcff9e4329a293141077a20e   url     application/http; msgtype=response      <urn:uuid:efa655dc-1404-11e6-a7dc-002590c8c43c>
```